# hidden implementation of member function (like static global function)

Tags: c++, c++11, linker

Let's assume you have two implementation source files with the same content:

```
// foo{a,b}.cpp
class Foo {
public:
  void bar();
}
void Foo::bar() { std::cout << "bar\n"; }
```

Implementing a normal function (not a member method), I would simply mark this method as `static`. But this has a different meaning on method declarations and can not be specified at the implementation.

How can I changed `foob.cpp` so that there will be no linker errors when both files are being compiled and linked together?

Comment: Oh... I wanted to say "put the include files in a namespace", but then I read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9765654/1016716). Oh well, I'm sure there is a good answer.

Comment: Well, I can't completely see which problem you actually want to solve here, but it smells like the [pimpl idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer#C.2B.2B) should be the right way to go (supposed `Foo` already has a public declaration).

Comment: Why are you compiling two implementation source files with the same content? Why not conditionally compile the _one_ you want to use to avoid duplicate definitions?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I think OP has over simplified his problem, but assume 2 different helper classes with same (poorly) name.

Comment: @Jarod42 Then of course your answer is the way to go (that's why I upvoted it already). We had such problems in production already BTW. Hard to catch runtime errors and confusing debug behaviors all over :-P ...

Comment: @Jarod42 Ah, that assumption makes a lot of sense, maybe the OP could clarify the question.

Comment: @Jarod42 Your assumption is correct, sorry for not being clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may put the whole in a unnamed namespace

```
// foo{a,b}.cpp
namespace
{

    class Foo {
    public:
      void bar();
    }
    void Foo::bar() { std::cout << "bar\n"; }
}
```

the class won't be visible outside and can be used only in current translation unit.

Comment: The drawback is, that the public interface of `Foo` is lost. I'm not actually sure this solves the OP's problem.

Comment: This works, thank you! :) @πάνταῥεῖ I'm not sure what you mean by `Foo` loosing its public interface. The one I want to wrap in `namespace { }` is only declared and used inside the `foob.cpp` file.

Answer (score 0):

The normal solution would be to remove the definition of `Foo::bar()` from `foob.cpp`.